# simple setting for traffic shaping

Tags: linux, networking, switch, traffic-shaping

I have:

- 2 linux boxes (A, B)
- 1 switch (S)
- 1 gateway (G)  [I have no control over this one]

> ```
> +---------------+          
> |  switch S     +-------+  
> +---+--------+--+       |  
>     |        |       +--+-+
>     |        |       | gw |
>  +--+-+   +--+-+     +----+
>  | A  |   | B  |           
>  +----+   +----+
> ```

Just for some testing purposes, I need to **shape traffic** coming from A before it reaches the gateway G. I inject traffic in A at the mac layer with `tcpreplay`, so I cannot do the shaping directly on A.

My idea is to:

- route to B all traffic from A
- apply traffic shaping on B (Linux traffic control or dummynet)
- reroute to gateway G all traffic from A arriving at B

Is my solution fine? Is there a simpler one that doesn't require two (Ethernet) network interfaces on B?

Would a **virtual network interface** on B make my life easier?

What are some typical commands I need in order to deploy the above setting (traffic shaping excluded)?

Comment: Oldie but goodie: http://lartc.org/wondershaper/

Answer (score 1):

Some ideas:

1. You can even shape the outgoing traffic coming from A and B even on GW!
2. If your switch were a little bit smarter... doesn't it have an embedded linux?
3. If you route that through B, beware, some network flag settings will be needed on B to handle the arp redirects correctly.

The main problem with your solution, that it will make the network of A dependant from B. Your network will be more unstable.

Although your solution makes from B linux essentially an intelligent, linux-based router. If "gw" and "switch S" are dummy, and B is smart, you could even consider to throw out at least one of them and make B to your real gateway.

Comment: Thank you so much for your tips! I forgot to specify that the gateway is the only component over which I have no control. The switch in question is `netgear prosafe 8 port 10/100 switch fs108 v2`; I looked at its specs and it doesn't look like it runs Linux, unfortunately.
Could you please elaborate more on point 3 or provide a simple example?
It is true that A will heavily depend on B, but this is just for testing purposes and my personal use, so I guess it's ok.

Comment: As for your last point, I believe I need an extra network interface on B in order to turn it into a router/gateway. Do you think a USB Ethernet adapter could do the job?

Comment: @RickyRobinson an USB->Ethernet adapter will work fine but will be limited by the ports bandwidth, ie. 480mbps for USB2.0, so about half of what you'll get with a normal Gigabit Ethernet card. But this looks like an experiment only for learning purposes so yeah it'll be fine, just don't do that in production.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any routing tricks for that, nor do you need a virtual interface.

You simply shape your traffic as it leaves system A.

Outline exactly what you want to do and it is trivial to write a 'tc' rule for it.

For example, say you want to limit A to 1mbit/s on all outgoing traffic:

```
# Flush tc
tc qdisc del dev eth0 root &> /dev/null

tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 1
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 1mbit
```

Done.

Run a speed test from A and you will see your incoming traffic is probably unaffected, but your outgoing traffic is limited 1 Mebibit per second.

Why do I say 'incoming *probably* unaffected'? Because if you have a very high incoming rate your ACK packets *might* exceed the 1Mbit limit, and get throttled.  And if your ACK's slow down, so does your incoming traffic.

---

If you are unable to use tc or iptables on A - such as if your traffic is invisible to tc/iptables - eg, tcpreplay, then you need to do the traffic control on B instead.

For this there are at least the following three ways to do it.

1. Buy a network card for B and put A/B1 on network 1, and B2/gateway on network 2. ie, B becomes a gateway. Now use 'tc' to shape A's traffic.
2. Multi home eth0 on B. ie, eth0:1 -> 172.16.5.0/24 and give A an address in this network. Configure B to forward traffic between eth0 and eth0:1, mark and shape traffic (tc) heading to the main gateway.
3. Use 'brctl' to create a bridge on eth0, and create interfaces for A/B and B/gw, and again mark and shape traffic (tc) heading to the main gateway.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I wanted to keep my post as short as possible, but I skipped an important detail: I do not shape traffic directly on A because I actually _inject_ traffic on A at the mac layer (with tcpreplay). With dummynet and linux traffic control working at the IP layer, I would bypass them.

Comment: The aim of my experiment is to manually select one or more traffic flows (defined by their (src addr, dst addr, src port, dst port, protocol) and insert them in a leaky bucket.

Comment: I added a 2nd section to the answer to cater for that.